# How to have a transparent background on a custom styled html range input?

Tags: html, css

I styled a range input following this article on CSS-Tricks : https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/#article-header-id-4
Here's a Codepen to explain : https://codepen.io/mavromatika/pen/wZaGJW

There is a white background around the range's track which can't get rid of. I made the image wider than the input so you can see the white background.

This background issue happens only in Firefox and not in Chrome.

Here's my CSS :

```
.image img {height: auto; width: 400px;;}
.slider {width: 380px; position:relative; top: -10px;}
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -14px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #367ebd;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 16px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #2a6495;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #3071a9;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #3071a9;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #367ebd;
}
```

And my HTML :

```
<div class="image"><img src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fvf-images%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F12%2Fsun-ra.jpg&f=1"></div>
<div class="slider"><input type="range"></div>
```

Comment: Please share your code. Don't expect us to do all the work. ;)

Comment: Please post a codepen with the issue or paste it here in the HTML/CSS editor

Comment: Sorry. There you go.

Answer (score 0):

Use **inherit** if you want to reset a value. In this case use **background: inherit** to reset the background color.

```css
body {
  background: black
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 18px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -14px;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #367ebd;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 16px 0;
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #2a6495;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #3071a9;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #3071a9;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #367ebd;
}

.range-wrapper {
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-wrapper">
  <input type="range" style="background:inherit;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. If I'm not mistaken, your solution works indeed in your example, but not in my "pen". I need to have a transparent background in order to see the image trough.